# Setting the value of one column to a list of shape (1, 2), where each of the 2 nested lists is the value of another column

Tags: python, pandas

Take for example that I have a DataFrame of two columns A and B, each consisting of a single number. I would now like to add another column, C which is a nested list, each internal list containing the single value from A and B.

```
           A      B                 C
index
    0    2.3    6.4    [[2.3], [6.4]] 
    1    5.6    2.8    [[5.6], [2.8]]
    2    8.2    9.0    [[8.2], [9.0]]
```

I have tried

```
df['C'] = [[x] for x in df[['A', 'B']].values.tolist()]
```

but this results in

```
           A      B               C
index
    0    2.3    6.4    [[2.3, 6.4]] 
    1    5.6    2.8    [[5.6, 2.8]]
    2    8.2    9.0    [[8.2, 9.0]]
```

Comment: `df['C'] = [ [[x[0]], [x[1]]] for x in df[['A', 'B']].values.tolist()]` ?
did this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `agg` i.e

```
df['C'] = df[['A','B']].agg(lambda x : ([x[0]],[x[1]]),1).apply(list)

   index    A    B               C
0      0  2.3  6.4  [[2.3], [6.4]]
1      1  5.6  2.8  [[5.6], [2.8]]
2      2  8.2  9.0  [[8.2], [9.0]]
```

In case you need speed use numpy's expand dims i.e

```
df['C'] = (df[['A','B']].values[:,:,None]).tolist()

df['C']
0    [[2.3], [6.4]]
1    [[5.6], [2.8]]
2    [[8.2], [9.0]]
Name: C, dtype: object
```

Comment: Nice to see u back :-)

Comment: @KOB no probs. If the solution was helpful you can vote for it.

Answer (score 2):

```
df['C']=df[['A','B']].apply(lambda x : [[x[0]],[x[1]]],1).values.tolist()
df
Out[1051]: 
   A  B           C
0  1  4  [[1], [4]]
1  2  5  [[2], [5]]
2  3  6  [[3], [6]]
```